# jenkins plugin is running on master node instead of on executor

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I wrote a jenkins plugin, and Im trying to use it in a pipeline.
I noticed that when im activating the pipeline, the **plugin** execution is running on the master node, instead of on the agent itself. (the rest of the steps executed on the agent as should be).
it's important to me that the plugin will run from the executor and not from the master node.
can I do something about it?

Comment: Probably a question for the [Jenkins Developer forum](https://groups.google.com/g/jenkinsci-dev). What is the plugin doing?

Answer (score 0):

You should restrict your build to run in the specific node
[image]

And be sure that this node does not have any warning in the "manage nodes" section...

Comment: the build itself is running on the agent node, its only the plugin that runs from the master.

Comment: It may need some modifications in the plugin according to https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Making+your+plugin+behave+in+distributed+Jenkins or maybe you can just deploy your plugin to the slaves and invoke with "execute shell". This should guarantee agent execution...

Comment: how can I deploy the plugin on the slave?

Comment: Assuming that it's a Java application, maybe you can just write a main routine, and call it from "execute shell" with required Jenkins parameters. I know it is not the best solution but it should work.